# Alternative for shadow darkness in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js, shadow

Now that shadow darkness is removed in r74 of Three.js, what alternative is there to still not make the shadows that dark? The default value is literally pitch black and there's no way to change it anymore.

Comment: `scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 0.3 ) );` ?

Comment: but that makes the whole scene more white / lit than it normally is.

Comment: Can you reduce the intensity of your other lights?

Comment: I'm also curious to know about this. Currently playing with a scene with 2 lights. Shadows come out pitch black. Typically the light values should add up, so that when you have a shadow from one light, shining another light onto that shadow should make the surface brighter.

Answer (score 1):

Since shadow darkness has been removed, to adjust shadow intensity you need to use ambient light. If no ambient light exists yet, make sure you add one to your scene. Then you adjust the intensity of your ambient and spotlights.